# Cooking bolognese sauce in stainless steel versus dutch oven?

Tags: food-safety, equipment, sauce

I've got a recipe I've been meaning on trying for sauce that indicates using an assumably ceramic dutch oven. Will I be in any dangerous territory if I use a stainless steel pot instead? I know not to use a reactive pot for tomatoes, just not sure if there are any other considerations?

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no.

Stainless steel is not "reactive"; generally that term refers to cast iron, aluminium, or copper cookware. So from that perspective you can swap it.

However, a recipe which expects a ceramic or enameled cast iron dutch oven probably is calibrated for cookware that has a high thermal mass and slow heating for its contents.  So if your stainless-steel pot has thin walls & bottom, you will need to adjust heat levels and cooking times, and stir more often to prevent burning.

Comment: I've got a cooking time of 3 hours for this sauce recipe, Are there additional measures I can take beyond low heat and frequent stirring to reduce the chance of burning the bottom of the pot here?

Comment: Oven or stovetop?

Comment: If your stove top won't go low enough to prevent burning, you can use the oven...or a heat diffuser for your burner.

Comment: +1 for heat diffuser. The poor-man's slow cooker, worth its weight in gold.

Comment: If using an oven make sure there aren't any plastics which will melt!